# XGboost keeps failing in Latest H2O stable release

Tags: h2o

I downloaded the latest release of H2O (3.18.0.1) and XGboost keeps failing. I am not sure whether to post to the JIRA issues or here.

```
h2o.init()
from h2o.estimators import H2OXGBoostEstimator
is_xgboost_available = H2OXGBoostEstimator.available()
train_path = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/bigdata/laptop/higgs_train_imbalance_100k.csv'
test_path = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/bigdata/laptop/higgs_test_imbalance_100k.csv'

df_train = h2o.import_file(train_path)
df_test = h2o.import_file(test_path)

# Transform first feature into categorical feature
df_train[0] = df_train[0].asfactor()
df_test[0] = df_test[0].asfactor()

param = {
      "ntrees" : 500
}

model = H2OXGBoostEstimator(**param)
model.train(x = list(range(1, df_train.shape[1])), y = 0, training_frame = df_train)
```

I can run random forest, GBM without an issue but xgboost keeps failing.

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04. Java Version: java version "1.8.0_161"; Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12); Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode). Anaconda Python 3.6

I reinstalled Anaconda and reinstalled JRE, but am still having the same issue.

It keeps giving me the following error:

```
    xgboost Model Build progress: |████████████████████████████████████████
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
        600                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
    --> 601                                                   chunked=chunked)
        602 

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
        386                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
    --> 387                     six.raise_from(e, None)
        388         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
        382                 try:
    --> 383                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
        384                 except Exception as e:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
       1330             try:
    -> 1331                 response.begin()
       1332             except ConnectionError:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
        296         while True:
    --> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
        298             if status != CONTINUE:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
        257     def _read_status(self):
    --> 258         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
        259         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
        585             try:
    --> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
        587             except timeout:

    ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
        439                     retries=self.max_retries,
    --> 440                     timeout=timeout
        441                 )

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
        638             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
    --> 639                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
        640             retries.sleep()

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
        356             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
    --> 357                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
        358             elif read is not None:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
        684         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    --> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
        686         raise value

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
        600                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
    --> 601                                                   chunked=chunked)
        602 

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
        386                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
    --> 387                     six.raise_from(e, None)
        388         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
        382                 try:
    --> 383                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
        384                 except Exception as e:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
       1330             try:
    -> 1331                 response.begin()
       1332             except ConnectionError:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
        296         while True:
    --> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
        298             if status != CONTINUE:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
        257     def _read_status(self):
    --> 258         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
        259         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
        585             try:
    --> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
        587             except timeout:

    ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py in request(self, endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
        399                                     headers=headers, timeout=self._timeout, stream=stream,
    --> 400                                     auth=self._auth, verify=self._verify_ssl_cert, proxies=self._proxies)
        401             self._log_end_transaction(start_time, resp)

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
         57     with sessions.Session() as session:
    ---> 58         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
         59 

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
        507         send_kwargs.update(settings)
    --> 508         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
        509 

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
        617         # Send the request
    --> 618         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        619 

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
        489         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
    --> 490             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
        491 

    ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    H2OConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-22-37b26d4dfbfd> in <module>()
          1 start = time.time()
    ----> 2 model.train(x = list(range(1, df_train.shape[1])), y = 0, training_frame = df_train)
          3 end = time.time()
          4 print(end - start)

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/estimators/estimator_base.py in train(self, x, y, training_frame, offset_column, fold_column, weights_column, validation_frame, max_runtime_secs, ignored_columns, model_id, verbose)
        229             return
        230 
    --> 231         model.poll(verbose_model_scoring_history=verbose)
        232         model_json = h2o.api("GET /%d/Models/%s" % (rest_ver, model.dest_key))["models"][0]
        233         self._resolve_model(model.dest_key, model_json)

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/job.py in poll(self, verbose_model_scoring_history)
         56                 pb.execute(self._refresh_job_status, print_verbose_info=lambda x: self._print_verbose_info() if int(x * 10) % 5 == 0  else " ")
         57             else:
    ---> 58                 pb.execute(self._refresh_job_status)
         59         except StopIteration as e:
         60             if str(e) == "cancelled":

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/utils/progressbar.py in execute(self, progress_fn, print_verbose_info)
        167                 # Query the progress level, but only if it's time already
        168                 if self._next_poll_time <= now:
    --> 169                     res = progress_fn()  # may raise StopIteration
        170                     assert_is_type(res, (numeric, numeric), numeric)
        171                     if not isinstance(res, tuple):

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/job.py in _refresh_job_status(self)
         91     def _refresh_job_status(self):
         92         if self._poll_count <= 0: raise StopIteration("")
    ---> 93         jobs = h2o.api("GET /3/Jobs/%s" % self.job_key)
         94         self.job = jobs["jobs"][0] if "jobs" in jobs else jobs["job"][0]
         95         self.status = self.job["status"]

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py in api(endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
        101     # type checks are performed in H2OConnection class
        102     _check_connection()
    --> 103     return h2oconn.request(endpoint, data=data, json=json, filename=filename, save_to=save_to)
        104 
        105 

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py in request(self, endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
        408             else:
        409                 self._log_end_exception(e)
    --> 410                 raise H2OConnectionError("Unexpected HTTP error: %s" % e)
        411         except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        412             self._log_end_exception(e)

    H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Comment: just installed 3.18.0.1 on Ubuntu with Java build 1.8.0_101-b13 and ran your code - all worked and was able to predict on test set.

Comment: Thanks. I did some more testing it looks like it is a browser issue. I ran it on Firefox instead of Chrome (using jupyter notebook --browser firefox) and it works fine. I re-tested on Chrome and it fails. I will re-install Chrome.

Comment: I always use Firefox too with no problems so far. Glad it resolved.

Comment: Actually I did further testing on another dataset and xgboost still fails. The connection to H2O fails after building 9 trees.

Comment: I tested xgboost and the dataset on Mac with H2O 3.18.0.1 and it failed as well. I rolled back to H2O 3.16.0.4 (using Python 3.5) and it works now. So it appears that the H2O Xgboost version has somehow changed in 3.18.0.1 and only becomes apparent on some datasets. I don't have time to properly troubleshoot, but it definitely appears to be an H2O xgboost issue.

Comment: it'd help if you could post it with minimal reproducible dataset for 3.18.0.1. Yes, xgboost got some major changes in this release.

Comment: there is at least one bug in xgboost fixed in 3.18.0.2: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5301?jql=project%20%3D%20PUBDEV%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20status%20in%20(Closed%2C%20Resolved)%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%203.18.0.2%20AND%20text%20~%20%22xgboost%22

Comment: There are some reproducible datasets at train_path = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/bigdata/laptop/higgs_train_imbalance_100k.csv'
test_path = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/bigdata/laptop/higgs_test_imbalance_100k.csv'. The datasets I am using are proprietary so I cannot share them.

Comment: I am also having this same issue with XGBoost on the AWS EC2 Ubuntu Deep Learning AMI on H2O version 3.18.0.1.

Comment: I think there are still some issues with XGBoost in the latest release (3.18.0.4). (It keeps crashing on certain data sets). I had to roll back to 3.16.0.